# Setting multiple default background images?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

The following code lets me set a default background image. Is it possible to set multiple custom backgrounds?

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array(
    'default-image' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/image1.png',   
) );
```

Comment: Do you mean an option to select from multiple images or do you want to use multiple images together as background?

Comment: @toscho I meant i can define some of the available background images, and the user can select one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of doing that as far as I can see. But I got hold of this plugin which allows you to create Image Sets and set random background images -> [Background Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/background-manager/)

Comment: This plugin has been closed and is no longer available for download.